# Using Tap widget in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use Tap from JQuery and I found some repeated texts at the bottom for Tap Headers and Text inside the Tap page. I have no idea why they are repeated there as shown in the attached picture.
My code is as follow.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>This is tap1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>This is tap2.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>This is tap3.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: picture].

Comment: Your tabs aren't working in the first place. Move all your css files before script files. And also move your <script></script> to the bottom of the page. Your code works at jsfiddle though https://jsfiddle.net/75eayb8b/

Comment: According to your Uploaded image I think you have problem with your HTML code check "> in bottom of Tab

Comment: Is working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/j76ztj07/ your problem is somewhere else